# OpenLayers TimeLine Integration

Tags: google-maps, openlayers, timelinemarkers

i am developing an api which uses timemap library with openlayers.. i send my data in array and everything is good but when i zoom in or zoom out all points coordinate are changing..
the address of i have used api is OpenLayers -TimeMap

http://timemap.googlecode.com/svn/tags/2.0/examples/basic_openlayers.html

you can see the marker is changing when zoom changed. how can i solve this problem thank u for your help...

Comment: Actually, I don't see any error. When I zoom and pan everything appears to act as expected. Could you please give a more precise description of what's going wrong?

Comment: @Niklas Ringdahl I'm using chrome 11 on linux and the markers are jumping around when changing zoom levels.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I developed this one, is similar but supports cluster strategy and it works even with huge amounts of data (like 5000 points).
https://github.com/volpino/openlayers-timeline

Demo: http://volpino.github.com/openlayers-timeline/

Comment: After a long time. I am trying to implement this example. I have marker history with start and end time which I need to display in the map and remove from the map while it is playing the slider or manual drag the slider. I must able to select two days (ex: 2021-01-10 to 2021-02-05) markers are (name: "marker one", start: 2021-01-10 10:20:00, end: 2021-01-10 11:50:00), slider time gap should be 15 mins or as selected from input. Need help to implement this

Answer (score 2):

I know that this is an old question, but I wanted to let you know that this was due to a bug in the Mapstraction library, and it's been fixed in Timemap.js v.2.0.1 - see: http://timemap.googlecode.com/svn/tags/2.0.1/examples/basic_openlayers.html